# Как админу можно править посты юзеров?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть users, среди users есть admin

```
 add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
```

Как можно править админу посты юзеров?

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :destroy]

def edit
   @posts = current_user.posts
end
def update
   @post = current_user.posts
   if @post.update(post_params)
      ...
   else
      render :edit
   end
end

def correct_user
    if current_user.admin?
      current_user.admin == current_user
    else
      @post= current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end
end



<%= simple_form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ов щи~ Я слабо представляю, как это вообще должно работать, даже без участия админов. А конкретно, интересен смысл строчек `@post = current_user.posts` (Запись в переменную для **одного** поста **целой коллекции** постов?) и `current_user.admin == current_user` (Сравнение `User` с булеаном? Оно ж всегда выдаст `false`, не?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как примерно это все должно выглядеть:

Для проверки прав на сущность можно воспользоваться гемом [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

```
# app/policies/post_policy.rb
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    user.admin?
  end
end

# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_and_authorize_post, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      ...
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def set_and_authorize_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
  end
end
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший гем, только немного подправил т.к у меня devise стоит 'def update?
    user.admin? || current_user = @user
  end'